# Issues With Mongoose $push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I really just need a second set of eyes here. I am using the Mongoose npm to create a new entry in my MongoDB. Then I am using that new entry in a few functions in the Async npm.

The issue that I am having is that I am getting the first three console logs, "hitter", "create", and "req.body.campaign_id" but nothing past that. I think it has to do with my $push in the first findByIdAndUpdate. Please see my code and schema below.

**Code! See async parallel "campaign" function**

```
Bid.create(req.body, function(err, bid){
        console.log('create')
        async.parallel({
            campaign: function(done) {
                console.log(req.body.campaign_id)
                Camapaign.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.campaign_id, {
                    $push: { bids: bid._id }
                }, {
                    safe: true,
                    upsert: true
                }, function(err, campaign){
                    console.log('camp', 2)
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        done(err)
                    } else {
                        done(null, campaign)
                    }
                });
            },
            user: function(done) {
                console.log('user', 1)
                User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.user_id, {
                    $push: {'bids': bid._id }
                }, {
                    safe: true,
                    upsert: true
                }, function(err, bid){
                    console.log('user', 2)
                    if(err) {
                        done(err)
                    } else {
                        done(null, bid)
                    }
                });
            }
        }, function(err, response){
            console.log('response')
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(response);
            }
        });
    })
```

**Campaign Schema**

```
var campaignSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    imgUrl:[String],
    shortDesc: { type: String, set: shortenDesc },
    longDesc:String,
    duration: Number,
    price: Number,
    desired_price: Number,
    bids: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'bidSchema' }],
    owner_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'userSchema' }
});
```

**User Schema**

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    twitter: {
        id: String,
        username: String,
        token: String,
        tokenSecret: String
    },
    facebook: {
        id: String
    },
    google: {
        id: String
    },
    campaigns: [campaignSchema],
    bids: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'bidSchema'}]
});
```

Please let me know if you need to see anything else. All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `Camapaign.findByIdAndUpdate` are you sure `Camapaign` isn't mispelled there? Shouldn't it be `Campaign`?

Comment: Hi Yuri! Thanks for responding. That was a typo and I fixed it. Still getting the same result. Still a good find

Comment: So I'm assuming `console.log('response')` does not get executed? Have you made sure that `bid._id ` is defined? If it is `undefined` bad things can happen with mongoose.

Comment: Response is never console logged. I can confirm that bid._id is not undefined. I replaced "console.log(req.body.campaign_id)" with "console.log(bid._id)" and got the value I wanted.

Comment: What exactly happens after it does the console.logs? Does it just hang there? Is there an error?

Comment: Thank you very much sir. All I needed was a second pair of eyes. And that my friends is coding in a nutshell!

Comment: Np :) It was throwing an error, but the error was being swallowed. You should probably investigate as to why, since its pretty useful to see errors in your console.